# Windows Azure Endpoints - how many can you have per subscription?

Tags: azure, limits, endpoints

Hej!

We have just started using Windows Azure and are now in the phase of designing our infrastructure. A question that I haven't really found a stright answer for is weather there is a limit on how many endpoints I can have per subscriptions. Some research told me 25 and then I found another place saying 150. I haven't found anything on MS offical Azure site or blog.

Does anyone know? and have the limit been confirmed?

Thanks in advance,
Lucas

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing *subscription* with *deployment* (a subscription is really a billing model for your Azure resources: compute, storage, bandwidth, etc. A deployment will have a collection of VMs (or web/worker roles) living behind a single `xxx.cloudapp.net` namespace. You'd then configure endpoints at a deployment level. For a Virtual Machine deployment, you'll only worry about external-facing (*input*) endpoints, since VMs can communicate internally across all ports. For web/worker Cloud Service deployments, you'll also have *input endpoints*.

Regard the number of endpoints per deployment: This number has grown over the years, and will continue to evolve. I'm not sure of the current limit, but... It's very simple to create an endpoint with PowerShell. With a simple for-loop, you should be able to create endpoints until an error is thrown.